# PHP Conversion Table

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP code which collect data from user´s input based on a range of given options (Banks).

***Piece of code:**

```
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $posted_data['bank']);
```

**Conversion table:**

[image]

Thus, if user select CITIBANK, it should return "001" into my code and not CITIBNAK itself. This should be applied for all the others choices.

What would be the best way to do it?
By using array or "if statement conditions" or even other solution?

Comment: Use a dropdown menu with the code in the `value` attribute and the name in the text.

Comment: `<option value="001">Citibank</option>`

Comment: Can't do it, cause the value is already set as "Bank" (this line code is not included in the post)

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Are you just asking how to create an associative array that translates the bank name to the code number?

Comment: `array('CITIBANK' => '001', 'BANK BOSTON' => '002', ...)`

Comment: @Barmar correct !  ☺️

Comment: @Barmar just need to add it below '$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $posted_data['bank']);' ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Use an associative array:

```
$bank_numbers = array('CITIBANK' => '001', 'BANK BOSTON' => '002', ...);
$banknum = $bank_numbers[$posted_data['bank']];
$domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $banknum);
```